# How to return back to home from 6th activity

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently i'm facing with the issue , I explain it in detail . I have created 6 activities from my home activity in my app. Like A ,B ,C ,D ,E ,F ,G . Consider A is home activity. In B i'm uploading my location to firebase database in current user id node , After that each and every activity like C, D, etc... I will upload some more details to my firebase database . And atlast in G activity i have set a button to redirect to home like in below code . It is going to home activity perfectly but when i again clicks on activity B . Its showing error and comes out . What it was showing is in activity  F ,i will retrieve some data's , in first time it doesn't shows error , but now its showing there is no reference in to retrieve from database. And one thing i'm doing in the app is ,as i said in Activity B i set location using map and upload to the database ,whenever i do this all other data's in my userid node will be removed and this location will set initially and followed by other.

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(InchargeEventConfirmedActivity.this,InchargeHomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

I had tried many possible ways like FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP etc... but not cleared, is there any best solution for my issue . Thanks in Advance

```
 private void Getdata2()
{
    Total_date_Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            final String From_date = dataSnapshot.child("From").getValue().toString();
            final String To_date = dataSnapshot.child("To").getValue().toString();

            Total_service_dates1.setText(From_date);
            Total_service_dates2.setText(To_date);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

In this above code its showing error in this line 
final String From_date = dataSnapshot.child("From").getValue().toString();
like there is no reference. but in 1st time it work's fine and after this activity i will pass to final activity by finish() . In some trials if After comes again to home and clicks Activity B again it redirects to activty E, If activity G in not set to finish() it will redirect to that activity.

```
2020-04-25 21:02:15.571 25013-25013/com.example.smileyservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smileyservice, PID: 25013
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.smileyservice.InchargeNewEvents.InchargeEventPreviewFinalActivity$8.onDataChange(InchargeEventPreviewFinalActivity.java:561)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

this error is showing when again i click on B activity again from activity A. which means after one loop. A B C D E F G (A) (B) .error . This error shows in Activity F.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry bro , i have done many alterations now . i cannot able to check because i converted that activities to fragments ...i tried , this can be resolved by using fragments , but still couldn't found a solution

Comment: I will upload the code where its showing error .

Comment: I uploaded now bro .

Comment: I think, you should remove value listener before finish()

Comment: could u explain in brief @Kasim Ozdemir